# Make Dailymotion videos work with Prettyphoto

Tags: jquery

After a lot of searching I've found [here](http://forums.no-margin-for-errors.com/discussion/1092/making-pretty-photo-dailymotion-videos-works/p1) some changes which should be done in order that Dailymotion videos should work with Prettyphoto.

I've done these changes and it's working... but not the first time after I refresh the page.

I mean that if I have this rel="prettyPhoto[videos]" and here I have 3 videos from youtube, vimeo and dailymotion, it's working only if I don't hit the first time the dailymotion video.
So if I hit the vimeo video and then going to next video...it's working. But if I refresh the page and hit the dailymotion video first... it's not working.

I'm sure this is a minor change because it doesn't recognize the path for the first time or something I don't know...

A live example is [here](http://randf.info/test/test.php).

The code added is this:

```
case 'dailymotion':
    correctSizes = _fitToViewport(movie_width,movie_height); // Fit item to viewport
    // Remove url's beginning
    var videoid = pp_images[set_position].replace(/http:\/\/www\.dailymotion\.com\/video\//i, '');
    // "Explode" the end of the string to catch the video id
    var spt = videoid.split('_');
    // Video id is index 0
    movie = 'http://www.dailymotion.com/swf/' + spt[0] + '?width=&theme=none&iframe=0&additionalInfos=0&autoPlay=1&hideInfos=0';
    toInject =  settings.iframe_markup.replace(/{width}/g,correctSizes['width']).replace(/{height}/g,correctSizes['height']).replace(/{wmode}/g,settings.wmode).replace(/{path}/g,movie);
break;
```

And, yes I found Casar Davorin's script but dailymotion doesn't work, even if he says is working.

Could somebody help me please?

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and the solution is quite simple, just replace `correctSizes` with `pp_dimensions`.

I've found the solution with the help of firebug. If you use Firefox, and not have it installed, I recommend that you install it. =)